# Firebid+C#   ошибка в CreateDatabase

Tags: c#, firebird

Добрый день.

Использую сервер Firebird 2.5 и Visual Studio 2005, язык C#. Есть задача программно создавать базу данных.

Применяю следующую конструкцию:

```
 FbConnectionStringBuilder connectString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
 connectString.Database = myPath; 
 connectString.Dialect = 3;
 connectString.UserID = "SYSDBA";
 connectString.Password = "my_pass";           
 connectString.Charset = "win1251";
 FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectString.ConnectionString, 8192, false, false);
```

Сам по себе код рабочий, базу создаёт. Но проблема в том, что всегда создаётся база со значением по умолчанию page_size=4096, хотя я и передаю в метод значение 8192.
Подскажите пожалуйста возможную причину ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

В [оригинальном руководстве](http://web.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/creating-a-database.html) как первый параметр для метода CreateDatabase используется на свойство ConnectionString, а строка, получаемая методом ToString(). Может в этом проблема7

Comment: завтра на работе проверю, может поможет. спасибо.
если у кого-то есть и другие идеи, буду рад, вдруг пригодятся.

Comment: нет, к сожалению, не помогло.
мне кажеться, ошибка даже не в коде... у меня установлен .Net 4.0.
А может быть причиной ошибки то, что я к проекту подключаю библиотеку FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll версии 2.1, ведь метод CreateDatabase появился только в Firebird 2.5 (если не ошибаюсь)  ?

Comment: да, точно. проверил тот же код в другом проекте, там применяется FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll версии 2.7, всё правильно сработало.

Comment: @TabakovAleksey , странный вы. Сервер одной версии, библиотеку другой :) Я бы тоже не знал, что создавать в таком случае.

Comment: Да просто раньше проект работал с сервером версии 2.1. Полгода назад перешли на 2.5. Тогда пробовал обновить библиотеку, но увидел, что во многих модулях придется делать изменения, там не поддерживалась какая-то функция из 2.1. Не стал время тратить, так и оставил старую.